# Pro and Cons of ISA Extensions on RISC-V cores

Tags: hardware-acceleration, riscv, instruction-set

Because RISC-V is an open-source architecture, one can come up with ISA extensions for dedicated purposes (e.g. [bit manipulation](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-bitmanip), or [cryptographic implementations](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.07041)).

While I understand that such extensions allow to speed up the calculations for a particular function, it is not clear to me what the drawbacks are.

In which case should I prefer a software implementation over an ISA extension if one that fits my needs is available? What are the additional costs to be taken into consideration when integrating several ISA extensions into a RISC-V core?

Comment: Effort required to adapt compilers to use the extension?

Comment: Having to maintain a complete software stack because non-standard extensions are usually not found at upstream. A software stack that supports the extension can include gcc, binutils, libc, libm, the linux kernel and libraries that profit from the extension.